# Hierarchical Metadata Navigation

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

We are currently using `Managed Metadata Navigation` for our `Current Navigation` section of our site. We have a bunch of libraries that we would like to separate into a hierarchy, like so:

```
-Home (/)
-Primary
----Documents (/documents)
-Secondary
----Community (/community)
```

In the example above, the items with parenthesis represent links and the ones without represent non-link headers for visual representation. We're running into an issue where when we create our term-set like this two things happen:

1. SharePoint forces upon us a Friendly URL, such as changing `/documents` to `primary/documents`. When I try to clear out `Configure Friendly URL settings for child terms` on our `Simple Link or Header` I get an unknown error pop up from JavaScript and the child links will not work.
2. If I don't mess with the `Simple Link or Header` item and click the child node, we lose all the parent nodes. This is the biggest offender and pain point for us. We can deal with the unruly friendly URL change, but we need to be able to see that entire navigation structure on every page of the site.

Below is how I am referencing the `Current Navigation` through the master page, if it helps:

```
 <SharePoint:SPNavigationManager id="QuickLaunchNavigationManager" runat="server" QuickLaunchControlId="V4QuickLaunchMenu" ContainedControl="QuickLaunch" EnableViewState="false">
     <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">
         <Template_Controls>
             <asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ShowStartingNode="True" id="QuickLaunchSiteMap" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" runat="server" />
         </Template_Controls>
     </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
     <SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="3" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="" />
</SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing was using CSS to style non-URL `Simple Links` differently since they are rendered as `<span>` instead of `<a>`.

For the URLs I did need as parents, I used `a[href=/local/url/]{ font-weight: bold; }`.

It's an *awful* solution but until I can find one better it will have to do.

Comment: Did you ever find a better way to do this? I have the same problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, or else I would have added it. Also, it stinks that my current projects don't have me working on this area so I'm afraid I'm no longer looking into it.